# Extract string that is between string X and string Y

Tags: c#, regex

There is a similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net). In that question X happens to be `(` and Y happened to be `)`. I am looking for something like

```
   public string GetStringBetweenStrings(string Source, string leftString, string rightString)
   {

       // implementation 
      Return middlePart;
   }
```

So that when I call that method as:

```
   var test = GetStringBetweenStrings("Hello World this is a test","World","test");

   // then test = " this is a ";
```

how can I build that function

Comment: What should it return for GetStringBetweenStrings("Hello World World this this is a test","World","test");?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same linked question, you have a more flexible answer that works for all strings, modified here:

```
public string GetStringBetweenStrings(string source, string leftString, string rightString)
{
    int start = source.IndexOf(leftString); // assume != -1
    int end = source.IndexOf(rightString);  // assume != -1 and >= start
    if (start == -1 || end == -1 || end < start) return String.Empty;
    return source.Substring(start + leftString.Length, end - start - rightString.Length - 1)
}
```

This assumes that both strings are contained in the source string. What behaviour do you want if either one isn't? Or if start is after end?

Obligatory regex version as per @Jack but updated into function:

```
public string GetStringBetweenStrings(string source, string leftString, string rightString)
{
    return Regex.Match(source, String.Format(@"(?<={0})(.*)(?={1})", 
                       Regex.Escape(leftString),
                       Regex.Escape(rightString)))
                       .Captures[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: You need to add the length of leftString to the start, otherwise your substring will contain leftString.

Comment: For the regex version, you probably want to use .*? as the current expression would match "a or b) or (c or d" from: "(a or b) or (c or d)". instead of "a or b" and "c or d".

Comment: Ohh and for the regex version, don't forget to call Regex.Escape on the boundary words.

Comment: The `Regex.Escape` stuff is great, updated. But the other example depends on what the original user wanted. Does he want it greedy or not? Does he want all matches, or just the first, or just the last?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=World).*(?=test)
```

http://regexr.com?30ph4

Here's a regex solution.  Replace `World` and `test` with your string variables when building the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IndexOf function to locate the two strings. Then use SubString to extract what you need.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOf` is the most straight forward. Make sure you offset the start to past the first string. I also added some (untested) code to handle if left/right could overlap.

```
public string GetStringBetweenStrings(string Source, string leftString, string rightString)
{
   var left = Source.IndexOf(leftString);
   var right = Source.IndexOf(rightString);
   while (right > -1 && left + leftString.Length >= right)
   {
       right = Source.IndexOf(rightString, right + 1);
   }
   if (left > -1 || right > -1 || left < right)
       return null;
   var start = left + leftString.Length;
   var end = right;
   return Source.Substring(start, end - start);
}
```