# How to remove part of a string that contains within bracket in C#?

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I extract a string of text that lies between two (brackets) using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net)

could anyone help to remove part of a string that is enclosed in bracket?

for example, I have a string parsed out of html/xml, so some comment remains in the string as following,

```
"hello <!-- this is not meant to be here --> world, please help me"
```

I want to remove the entire comments includes `<!--, words, and -->`, and leave as "hello world, please help me"

Thank you!

Comment: Please post code if you have tried any so we can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex;

```
 string x ="hello <!-- this is not meant to be here --> world, please help me";
 string y = Regex.Replace(x, "<!--.*?-->", "");
```

Comment: can u pls share the tool u've used as ur reply was too quick..i want to learn to make regex expressions...

Comment: I use LinqPad to write adHoc code. Really handy tool

Comment: Also, this: http://regexhero.net/

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "hello <!-- this is not meant to be here --> world, please help me";

int start = text.IndexOf("<!--");
int end = text.IndexOf("-->") - "-->".Length;

string cleanText = text.Remove(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var regex = new Regex("[<][^<]*[>]"); // or "[<]!--[^<]*--[>]"
            var input = "hello <!-- this is not meant to be here --> world, please help me";
            var output = regex.Replace(input, String.Empty); // hello  world, please help me
        }
    }
}
```

This regex pattern - `[<][^<]*[>]` - means:

- open square bracket - [<]
- then any number (*) of characters which are not an open square bracket - [^<]
- finally, closing square bracket - [>]

`regex.Replace(input, String.Empty);` - this means: replace all substrings matching the above pattern with an empty string.