# How to match string in quotes using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Suppose I have the following text in a text file

First Text

"Some Text"

"124arandom txt that should not be parsed!@

"124 Some Text"

"어떤 글"

this text a"s well should not be parsed

I would like to retrieve `Some Text`, `124 Some Text` and `어떤 글` as matched strings. The text is read line by line. Catch is, it has to match foreign languages as well if it is inside quotes.

Update:
I found out something weird. I was trying some random stuff and found out that:

```
string s = "어떤 글"
Regex regex = new Regex("[^\"]*");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(s);
```

matches have a count = 10 and have generated some empty items inside (The parsed text is in index 2). This might've been why I kept getting empty string when I was just doing Regex.Replace. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you looked at related questions, when posting this one?

Comment: Is each quoted string guaranteed to be on its own line, with the `"` character at the start and end of the line?

Comment: @JleruOHeP I did and they weren't really helpful

Comment: Even first one from the right - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Dan Yes, every quoted string is guaranteed to be on its own line.

Comment: @JleruOHeP Please look at the catch I wrote above and you will see how my question differs. It needs to capture any possible text in quotation mark in all languages.

Also, the link you provided shows how to match a string between the brackets.

Comment: You aren't anchoring the regex, it may start to match anywhere within the string. Because you use a star not a plus you allow empty matches. There is an empty match before the first quote and after the last quote.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you read the text line by line, then the regex

```
"[^"]*"
```

will find all quoted strings, unless those may contain escaped quotes like `"a 2\" by 4\" board"`.

To match those correctly, you need

```
"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"
```

If you don't want the quotes to become part of the match, use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")
(?<=")(?:\\.|[^"\\])*(?=")
```

These regexes, as C# regexes, can be created like this:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"(?<="")[^\""]*(?="")");
Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"(?<="")(?:\\.|[^""\\])*(?="")");
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work for foreign languages. What could be the possible cause?

Comment: `[^"]` matches any character except quotes, so it should match characters in foreign languages, too. How exactly are you using the regex? Might there be right-to-left languages involved?

Comment: @l46kok: You need to use verbatim strings and to escape the quotes for the string that contains the regex: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"""[^\""]*""");`

Comment: What you gave me above seems to be working excellently but it's also capturing the quotes along with the matched string. Is there a way to avoid the quotes?

Comment: In other words,

wordHovered = Regex.Match(wordHovered, @"""[^\""]*""").Value;

gives me 

"Text"

instead of

Text

Comment: @l46kok: Sorry for the delay, I was out of office; I have now edited my answer to exclude the quotes from the match.

Comment: So close; I wanted the same thing for single quotes, but this wouldn't cover contractions...

Answer (score 0):

.
You can use a regular expression and then try to match it with any text you want. can be in a loop or what ever you need.

```
string str = "\"your text\"";
//check for at least on char inside the qoutes
Regex r = new Regex("\".+\"");
bool ismatch = r.IsMatch(str);
```

Comment: I thought quotes were escaped in C# by doubling?

Comment: no they don't. the escape char is '\' if you want the qout to be in your text you need to put \ before it or @ before the all text, like this: @""hi all"" = "\"hi all\"" = printed text "hi all"

Comment: Ah, OK, I always use `@` strings for regexes in C# because there is a high likelihood that backslashes will be needed for the regex itself :)

Comment: if you need to add \ to the string just write \\

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript (and Typescript) the correct RegExp is:

```
let matchDoubleQuotedString = /"(?:[^"]|\")*"/
```

```
let matchSingleQuotedString = /'(?:[^']|\')*'/
```

```
let matchQuotedString = /"(?:[^"]|\")*"|'(?:[^']|\')*'/
```

Match either a **single quote character** or a **backslash and the quote**
(zero or more times)