# Extracting string between two characters?

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio-2010

I want to extract email id between `< >`

for example.

input string : `"abc" <abc@gmail.com>; "pqr" <pqr@gmail.com>;`

output string : `abc@gmail.com;pqr@gmail.com`

Comment: is ; the delimeter of multiple matches or must it be matched from the input string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract a string of text that lies between two (brackets) using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net)

Comment: @Rawling That question refers to extract string between only two brackets here I've multiple < >;

Comment: You said extract email from <>, yet ";" is outside of the brackets. Thats why I was asking.

Comment: I want to separate multiple extracted email-id's with `;`

Comment: @Vis Regular expressions, as used in the first answer to that question, should let you get multiple matches in your case, with a little bit of adaptation.

Comment: @Vis - Is none of the answers below working for you?

Comment: @Rawling: I'm wondering, aren't regular expression quite a bit of an overkill here? Unless we want to check the validity of the e-mail addresses (which is not stated in the question), other ways of finding two alternating characters are probably more readable in code and thereby enhance maintainability, don't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string input = @"""abc"" <abc@gmail.com>; ""pqr"" <pqr@gmail.com>;";
var output = String.Join(";", Regex.Matches(input, @"\<(.+?)\>")
                                    .Cast<Match>()
                                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value));
```

Comment: using regex will be the main solution here.

Answer (score 11):

Without regex, you can use this:

```
public static string GetStringBetweenCharacters(string input, char charFrom, char charTo)
    {
        int posFrom = input.IndexOf(charFrom);
        if (posFrom != -1) //if found char
        {
            int posTo = input.IndexOf(charTo, posFrom + 1);
            if (posTo != -1) //if found char
            {
                return input.Substring(posFrom + 1, posTo - posFrom - 1);
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

And then:

`GetStringBetweenCharacters("\"abc\" <abc@gmail.com>;", '<', '>')`

you will get

`abc@gmail.com`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

Tested

```
string input = "\"abc\" <abc@gmail.com>; \"pqr\" <pqr@gmail.com>;";
matchedValuesConcatenated = string.Join(";", 
                                Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=<)([^>]+)(?=>)")
                                .Cast<Match>()
                                .Select(m => m.Value));
```

(?<=<) is a non capturing look behind so < is part of the search but not included in the output

The capturing group is anything not > one or more times

Can also use non capturing groups @"(?:<)([^>]+)(?:>)"

The answer from LB +1 is also correct.  I just did not realize it was correct until I wrote an answer myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`String.IndexOf(char, int)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y.aspx) to search for `<` starting at a given index in the string (e.g. the last index that you found a `>` character at, i.e. at the end of the previous e-mail address - or `0` when looking for the first address).

Write a loop that repeats for as long as you find another `<` character, and everytime you find a `<` character, look for the next `>` character. Use the [`String.Substring(int, int)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) to extract the e-mail address whose start and end position is then known to you.

Comment: -1? Any reason? If there is anything incorrect about the answer, please let me know so I can improve it.

Comment: If you can objectively highlight any errors in this answer that would warrant the repeated downvoting, please feel free to do so. I'm eager to learn more, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Could use the following regex and some linq.

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"\<(.*?)\>");
        var input= @"""abc"" <abc@gmail.com>;  ""pqr""  <pqr@gmail.com>";
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
       var res = string.Join(";", matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Replace("<","").Replace(">","")).ToArray());
```

The <> brackets get removed afterwards, you could also integrate it into `Regex` I guess.

Answer (score -2):

```
string str = "\"abc\" <abc@gmail.com>; \"pqr\" <pqr@gmail.com>;";
        string output = string.Empty;
        while (str != string.Empty)
        {
            output += str.Substring(str.IndexOf("<") + 1, str.IndexOf(">") -1);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(">") + 2, str.Length - str.IndexOf(">") - 2).Trim();
        }
```

Comment: There should be an *explanation* for an answer, not only some code for mindless copy&pasting ...