# C# substring from specific character until first space

Tags: c#

I want to replace string that start with specific character until first space space after that (or maybe first specific character) with another string.

For example If we have a string like this:

```
aaa bbb ccc @ddd eee fff @ggg hh#iii. jj
```

I want to make it something like this.

```
aaa bbb ccc @MMM eee fff @MMM hh#MMM. jj
```

[I found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108582/extracting-string-between-two-characters) but that's not helpful for me.

**UPDATE:**

I want to replace all word that start with `@` or `#` and ended with  or `.` or something else that I want with a string like `MMM`.

> In a real example I only know some work start with `@` or `#`.

Comment: Soooooo [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `str = str.Replace("@ddd", "@MMM").Replace("@ggg", "@OOO")` etc. What's the problem?

Comment: I update it. please see again.

Comment: The update doesn't change anything. Use `string.Replace()`...

Comment: @Jonesopolis In real example I only know some work start with `@` or `#`.

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't change anything at all.  Use `String.Replace(..)`

Comment: I think he is stating he wants to replace from the '@' or '#' and continue through to the next ' ' character, but doesn't know what will be in that location. This might be a regular expression need.

Comment: @Amy Maybe new update improve the question. please see it again.

Comment: Now *that* update changes things.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would get a good start to what you are wanting, although may need some polish based on your specific needs.

```
    string val = "aaa bbb ccc @ddd eee fff @ggg hh#iii. jj";
    string[] values = val.Split(' '); //identify the separate entities you want split
    val = "";//reset string to empty string
    foreach(string a in values)
    {
        if (a.Contains('@') || a.Contains('#'))
            val += a[0] + "MMM"; //change the values to 'M' of the original
        else
            val += a;
    }
    return val; //return the string with values changed to 'M'
```

Single line example using Linq as provided by Juharr in the comments

```
return string.Join(" ", val.Split().Select(s => s.StartsWIth('@') || s.StartsWith('#') ? s[0] + "MMM" : s));
```

Comment: That produces `"aaa bbb ccc @ddd eee fff @ggg hh#iii. jjaaabbbccc@MMMeeefff@MMMhMMMjj"`

Comment: Now it's just `"aaabbbccc@MMMeeefff@MMMhMMMjj"`  You need to add the spaces back.

Comment: @juharr You are correct, A space will likely need to be added in, as well as better handling for what appears to be data mid sequence.

Comment: Could just do `return string.Join(" ", val.Split().Select(s => s.StartsWIth('@') || s.StartsWith('#') ? s[0] + "MMM" : s));`

Comment: Nice usage of Linq.

Answer (score 0):

```
    string example = "aaa bbb ccc @ddd eee fff @ggg hh"; //Init the input 
    string[] splitExample = example.Split(' '); //Split the string after every space into an array of substrings
    for (int i = 0; i < splitExample.Length; i++) //Iterate through each substring
    {
        if (splitExample[i] != null) //Check if the currently tested string exists within the array
        {
            if (splitExample[i] == '@') // Test if the first char of the currently tested substring is '@'
            {
                splitExample[i] = "@MMM"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break; //Exit the loop if the tested string does not exist
        } 
    }
    string exampleOutput;
    foreach(string append in splitExample) //Iterate through the array and add the now modified substrings back together
    {
        exampleOutput = exampleOutput + " " + append;
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, this was just off of my head

Comment: Your for loop needs a little help to do anything, or compile.

Comment: Yeah I didn't exactly make this in an IDE, I wrote this with extra time in my boring Computer Essentials class :/

Comment: Your answer is definitely better even when mine does work