# How to extract a string from a string between specific Chars in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to extract specific string from a string between these chars "@" and "#".

For example my string is

```
string myStr= "*-34@Apple#*-42@Banana#*-42@Orange#........";
```

I Want to extract Apple, Banana, Orange from the string!

**Note:** I need solution with dynamic approach as myStr length can be variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting string between two characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108582/extracting-string-between-two-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MatchCollection` we can try:

```cs
string myStr = "*-34@Apple#*-42@Banana#*-42@Orange#*........";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myStr, "-\\d+@(.*?)#\\*");
Console.WriteLine("There were {0} matches:", matches.Count);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This prints:

```
There were 3 matches:
Apple
Banana
Orange
```

Comment: Dear @Tim thanks for the answer, but please Consider last char in the string is '#' while not '*'

Comment: For example if my string is "*-34@Apple#*-42@Banana#*-42@Orange#" it will skip the last result

Comment: Then match on `-\d+@(.*?)#`