# Pattern that Matches All Text Between Numerals in String

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I am trying to use RegEx to create a group for each verse in a chapter of the Bible. For example, let's say that the text is the following:

```
1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,
Isaac the father of Jacob,
Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
Perez the father of Hezron,
Hezron the father of Ram,
```

The result that I am seeking is 3 groups as follows:

Group #1:

```
1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:
```

Group #2:

```
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,
Isaac the father of Jacob,
Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,
```

Group #3:

```
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
Perez the father of Hezron,
Hezron the father of Ram,
```

...(an added bonus would be to replace any line breaks of the strings in each group with a space)

I have tried many different patterns, but have had no success. The pattern that I last tried is `@"([^0-9][\s\S^0-9]*[^0-9])"` which resulted in two groups, each containing all of the text, save for the first digit.

I am using C#. [Picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkbzj.png)

What pattern would give me the result I am looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of sharing it as an image.

Comment: Try `\d(\D+?)\d?`.  Numbers can be matched with `\d` while `\D` matches non-numeric characters. `*?` matches the minimum number of characters that satisfy the pattern.

Comment: All info you need (including search terms to continue your research) is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12111281/477420... While probably a duplicate I don't expect one to be able to generalize one character to group of characters from the same class... so keeping the question open - someone probably will find an exac dup.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That would not work. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Answer (score 1):

Well this was interesting to think about.

- \d+: Matches one or more digits (the verse number).
- [\s\S]*?: Matches any character, including newlines, but as few as possible.
- (?=(\n\d+)|$): Positive lookahead to ensure matching stops at the start of the next numbered verse or the end of the text.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = @"1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,
Isaac the father of Jacob,
Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
Perez the father of Hezron,
Hezron the father of Ram,";

        string pattern = @"(\d+[\s\S]*?)(?=(\n\d+)|$)";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);

        int groupCount = 1;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            string verse = Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"\n", " ");
            Console.WriteLine($"Group #{groupCount}:\n\n{verse}\n");
            groupCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all text without using any non greedy quantifiers, you can match a line starting with 1 or more digits 0-9 followed by a word boundary, and then match all following lines that do not start with that same  pattern.

Then for each match you can replace 1 or more newlines with a space.

The pattern matches:

- `(?m)` Inline modifier for to enable multiline
- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+\b` Match 1+ digits 0-9 followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `[\r\n]+` Match 1 or more newlines
  - `(?![0-9]+\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+ digits followed by a word boundary directly to the right
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y7DCtB/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dCKbTP).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pattern = @"(?m)^[0-9]+\b.*(?:[\r\n]+(?![0-9]+\b).*)*";
    string input = @"1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,
Isaac the father of Jacob,
Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
Perez the father of Hezron,
Hezron the father of Ram,";

    var items = Regex
    .Matches(input, pattern)
    .Select(match =>  Regex.Replace(match.Value, "[\r\n]+", " "));

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Output

```
--------------------------------
1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham: 
--------------------------------
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac, Isaac the father of Jacob, Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers, 
--------------------------------
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar, Perez the father of Hezron, Hezron the father of Ram,
```

Comment: I love this answer so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
data="""1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:
2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,
Isaac the father of Jacob,
Jacob the father of Judah and his brothers,
3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,
Perez the father of Hezron,
Hezron the father of Ram,
"""

results=re.findall(r'\b\d+\s.*?(?=\n+|\d+\s|$)', data, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

print(results)

\bd+\s.*?  find one or more digits then non greed capture words
(?=\n+|\d+\s|$) look ahead for a carriage return or one or more digits followed by a space.  search until end of string
```

output

```
['1 This is the genealogy of Jesus the Messiah the son of David, the son of Abraham:', '2 Abraham was the father of Isaac,', '3 Judah the father of Perez and Zerah, whose mother was Tamar,']
```