# Getting specific part of text in a strict text

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0

Assume that there is a text which like below:

`string str = @"stackoverflow(`**stack**`:stackoverflow)overstackflow(`**over**`:stackoverflow)";`

I want to get bold fields.
I think I have to find "(" and ":" in text and get the text between of them. Isn't it?

Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean the backticks in the middle of your string? At the moment they're un-coding your tags.

Comment: assume that there is a text and I want to get the text beween ( and : operators. How can I do it?

Comment: do you want to get yes/no answer? why not try it yourself?

Comment: Using `substring` and `IndexOf` will help you.

Comment: Firstly I want to learn is it a good way? I can try it I wonder any ideal way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps with plain `string` methods:

```
IList<String> foundStrings = new List<String>();
int currentIndex = 0;
int index = str.IndexOf("(", currentIndex);
while(index != -1)
{
    int start = index + "(".Length;
    int colonIndex = str.IndexOf(":", start);
    if (colonIndex != -1)
    {
        string nextFound = str.Substring(start, colonIndex - start);
        foundStrings.Add(nextFound);
    }
    currentIndex = start;
    index = str.IndexOf("(", currentIndex);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zQWIgH)

Comment: @Tim Do you use only [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) when you answering in SO, or use also Visual Studio? Is ideone faster ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: For demo purposes only. It's not faster, it uses mono which has many limitations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter For other problems, Visual Studio or Linqpad ?

Comment: @SonerGönül I think he use it only for demo

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post and you can find the answer.

> [How do I extract text that lies between parentheses (round brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-brackets-using-net)

You only need to do small changes to that regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
string strRegex = @"\((.+?)\:";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"stackoverflow(stack:stackoverflow)overstackflow(over:stackoverflow)";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no point checking `myMatch.Success` but you might want to show how to get the `Value` out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for something like:

```
Regex matcher = new Regex(@"([^():}]+)\(([^():}]*):([^():}]*)\)");
MatchCollection matches = matcher.Matches(str);
```

This will look through your input for everything that looks like `group1(group2:group3)`. (If any of the groups contains a `(`, `)` or `:` the whole thing will be ignored as it can't figure out what's meant to be where.)

You can then get the matched values as e.g.

```
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First: {0}, Second: {1}, Third{2}",
        m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

so if you just want the bits between the `(` and the `:` you can use

```
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = @"stackoverflow(stack:stackoverflow)overstackflow(over:stackoverflow)";
            Console.WriteLine(ExtractString(str));
        }

        static string ExtractString(string s)
        {
            var start = "(";
            int startIndex = s.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
            int endIndex = s.IndexOf(":", startIndex);
            return s.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        }
```

Result is `stack` but you can use it in a `foreach` loop for iteration to your string.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/kMyhjs)