# Regex - Remove all characters before and after

Tags: regex

Is is it possible to remove all characters before (and including) every character to third `'` and also everything after (and including) the fourth `'`, basically isolating the text inside the 3rd and 4th `'`

example:

```
a, 'something', 'ineedthistext', 'moretexthere'
```

should result in

```
ineedthistext
```

Comment: regex don't manipulate strings.  they just match them.  all the string manipulation that uses regex is language specific

Comment: Why don't you use a explode/split function ?

Comment: What language? If Java, have you considered String.split?

Comment: the regex works `^.*?'.*?'.*?'(.*?)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex might not be the best tool to do this (split by comma/apostrophe might actually be a better way), but if you want regex...

Maybe instead of removing all the characters before and after `ineedthistext`, you can capture `ineedthistext` from the group.

I would use something like:

`^.*?'.*?'.*?'(.*?)'`

Tested with [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9qTdcp8rwb).

Comment: i don't think that you necessaraly want '+' in this case unless you want to specifically exclude empty strings

Comment: @SamIam I think you're right. I was assuming that the elements of the 'list' couldn't be empty... but better be careful! I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public String stringSplit(String input) {
    String[] wordArray = input.split("'");
    String requiredText = wordArray[3];
    return requiredText;
}
```

This will work if you always want the bit between the 3rd and 4th '.

Answer (score 0):

Derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378447/1049308), a possible solution is:

```
Regex.Match(yourString, @"\('[^']*)\)").Groups[2].Value
```

The code looks for all strings embedded between 2 single quotes, and puts them in groups. You need the 2nd group.

To alter your string directly, effectively removing the unwanted characters, you could use:

```
yourString = Regex.Match(yourString, @"\('[^']*)\)").Groups[2].Value
```