# How to check if there is some text between 2 chars?

Tags: c#, string, char

I'm making a little HTML editor and I would like to know, how to return string/array of chars, that are/is between 2 characters (like > and < or " and ")

Example:

```
<>Text inside > and <<> or "Text inside " and "".
```

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) if you  want to parse html instead of string-methods or regex. However, the sample you've posted is not valid html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract a string of text that lies between two (parenthesis) using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-parenthesis-using-net)

Comment: Finally useful to add a link to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/870604 !

Comment: Damn sorry guys, I forgot add c# to header

Comment: @user3923447 Actually the title shouldn't contain `C#` as there already is a tag

Comment: @Teslo You're maybe right. I need to look at regex, what actually does.

Comment: @ken2k but some guys like me forgot sometimes read the tags

Comment: @BigBang1112 The established policy on SO is not to put tags in the title, regardless of one's preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) - they're perfect for this purpose.

Quick tip to help you along - the following expression should give you a match if 'abc' sits between the > and < characters:

```
(?<=\>)abc(?=\<)
```

Comment: I don't know if I agree that RegEx is "perfect for this purpose". As explained in [this SO Question and Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la), using RegEx to parse HTML is not really possible.

Comment: True, if the OP cares about validating the HTML then this is the wrong way to go, but I was thinking more along the lines of extracting the contents of already validated HTML - displaying hints for attribute values etc. Either way, validating HTML is a different kettle of fish - I wouldn't even bother trying to do it myself.