# Get text between 2 same symbols

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have string : `asf_grgrh_wrar`(just to show).

How to get `grgrh` that are between 2 `_`?

---

```
  var first = picture.IndexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var second = picture.IndexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal) + string.substring(first ).indexOf("_", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

This what i try (try to get first and second symbol indexes to cut string between them). Problem in getting second index.

Comment: What attempts did you make and what went wrong exactly?

Comment: IndexOf, Substring, Regex. the possibilities are endless and this kind of question has been asked millions of times here. Searching a bit before? [Find a string between two strings](http://www.bing.com/search?q=find%20string%20between%20two%20strings&qs=n&sk=&form=BDKTKB&pc=BDT5&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-that-lies-between-two-parenthesis-using-net?rq=1

Comment: @Steve, i saw this post, but for my case symbols aren't parenthesis

Comment: Being able to take an existing solution and trivially modify it is something we expect you to be able to do. If that isn't possible, SO might not be the place for you.

Comment: @user3625486 look at the more simple answers that use IndexOf and Substring. Look at them and cross reference the docs in MSDN about the methods used. You should be able to modify those answers to fit your needs.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think you have a point here, but do not be so harsh with this guy. Just don't give the fish but [teach how to fish](http://zenpencils.com/comic/84-chinese-proverb-give-a-man-a-fish/). Goodnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use the overload of `IndexOf` that takes a start index when you look for the second character:

```
int first = picture.IndexOf('_');
int second = picture.IndexOf('_', first + 1);

string part = picture.Substring(first + 1, second - first - 1);
```