# Parse a string, keeping all of the matches in between given strings (multi-character delimiters)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

This is very similar to the question here: [How do I extract text that lies between parentheses (round brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets) which I see this Regex code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("User name [[sales]] and [[anotherthing]]", @"\[\[([^)]*)\]\]");
```

But that doesn't seem to work with multi-character delimiters?  This might not even be the correct way to go, but I am sure I am not the first to try this and I am drawing a blank here - anyone?

Comment: Use `Regex.Matches`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this could be solved checking intellisense suggestions or just checking what methods `Regex` object supports on MSDN.

Comment: I updated it to be more accurate to my problem.  Wiktor answered the original question, but turns out that didn't work so well for my actual case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@"\[\[([^)]*)\]\]"` pattern matches two consecutive `[[`, followed with zero or more characters other than a `)` and then followed with two `]]`. That means, if you have a `)` inside `[[...]]`, there won't be a match.

To deal with multicharacter-delimited substrings, you can use 2 things: either lazy dot matching, or unrolled patterns.

**Note**: to get *multiple matches*, use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx) as I wrote in my other answer.

**1. Lazy dot solution**:

```
var s = "User name [[sales]] and [[anotherthing]]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[{2}(.*?)]{2}", RegexOptions.Singleline)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%7B2%7D(.*%3F)%5D%7B2%7D&i=User%20name%20%5B%5Bsales%5D%5D%20and%20%5B%5Banotherthing%5D%5D). The `RegexOptions.Singleline` modifier is necessary for the `.` to match newline symbols.

**2. Unrolled regex solution**:

```
var s = "User name [[sales]] and [[anotherthing]]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[{2}([^]]*(?:](?!])[^]]*)*)]{2}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
```

With this one, `RegexOptions.Singleline` is not necessary, and it is much more efficient and faster.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5B%7B2%7D(%5B%5E%5D%5D*(%3F%3A%5D(%3F!%5D)%5B%5E%5D%5D*)*)%5D%7B2%7D&i=User%20name%20%5B%5Bsales%5D%5D%20and%20%5B%5Banotherthing%5D%5D)

Comment: Wow, this is fantastic, thank you!  I am impressed with your regex knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches the specified input string for **all occurrences** of a specified regular expression.

Sample code:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("User name (sales) and (anotherthing)", @"\(([^)]*)\)")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: this works great, but... apparently my regex is garbage, because it is actually for the pattern [[something]] - and subbing "\[\[" for "\(" isn't seeming to work right?

Comment: If you have multicharacter delimiters, the negated character class alone won't help. I will post another answer.