# Regex to extract text between parenthesis paired with asterisk

Tags: c#, regex

This is a slightly different from similar posts in that the parenthesis are paired with an asterisk. 
example input:

> yada yada (* need to grab this text *) yoda

I thought [Jennifers post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets/378446#378446) could be altered for this but my attempts fail.

```
       //Regex regex = new Regex("\\((?<TextInsideBrackets>\\w+)\\)"); //original
        Regex regex = new Regex("\\(\\*(?<TextInsideBrackets>\\w+)\\*\\)"); // my attempt
        string incomingValue = "Autocycleprestartcase := 20;   (* Yayitme ve Konveyoru bosaltabilir *)";
        string insideBrackets = null;
        Match match = regex.Match(incomingValue);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            insideBrackets = match.Groups["TextInsideBrackets"].Value;
        }
```

Suggestions?

Also, I'd like to remove the enclosed text, with the enclosing parethesis/asterisk pairs, from the input line.

So the output of above would give me

> yada yada yoda

and the value

> need to grab this text

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it is https://stackoverflow.com/a/378447/3832970 that you should use.

Comment: @Wiktor, that answer is for everything between parenthesis, but for this requirement the parenthesis *needs* to be paired with an asterisk.

Comment: Then you accepted an incorrect answer. `[\w ]+` only matches 1 or more spaces or letters/digits/`_`. You need `@"\(\*(.*?)\*\)"`

Comment: Hmm. I think I understand but when I tried to make it fail with "(z  z)" instead of "(* *)" it worked as expected. Can you give me a use case where Thomas answer does not work?

Comment: `(* welcome! *)` - `!` is not a word/space char. A `,`, `:`, `;`, etc. will also make it fail. You say you need *everything between parenthesis*.

Comment: You're right in that my comment to you wasn't specific enough, but the original post was clear I think. I'll edit the comment. However it is not letting me edit the comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\(\\*(?<TextInsideBrackets>[\\w ]+)\\*\\)"); 
                                                     ^^^^^^
```

to allow spaces

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Can you show me how to remove the contained text and the surrounding parenthesis/asterisk pairs? (see edit)

Comment: Use Regex.Replace instead of Regex.Match @SkippyVonDrake

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to get both the values while re-using the pattern dynamically:

```
string incomingValue = "Autocycleprestartcase := 20;   (* Yayitme ve Konveyoru bosaltabilir *)";
string pattern = @"\(\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*\)";
string insideBrackets = Regex.Match(incomingValue, pattern).Groups[1].Value ?? string.Empty;
Console.WriteLine(insideBrackets); // => Yayitme ve Konveyoru bosaltabilir 
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(incomingValue, $@"\s*{pattern}", string.Empty)); // => Autocycleprestartcase := 20;
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/TDU0uJ)

**Pattern details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(` (note the single backslash is used as the string is defined via a *verbatim string literal*, `@""`)
- `\*` - a literal `*`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (trimming the value from the left)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing zero or more chars other than newline, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (trimming from the right)
- `\*` -  a literal `*`
- `\)` - a literal `)`

To get the second value, you may use the same pattern, but add `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces) at the beginning, what is done with `Regex.Replace(incomingValue, $@"\s*{pattern}", string.Empty)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Eventually it'll sink in. (mabye)

Comment: @SkippyVonDrake: I think my answer fully covers your question. If you have any doubts or questions regarding this solution, please let me know.

Comment: Yes your answer is more correct. For my needs I could use either solution because the enclosed text is always just letters. Thanks again.