# Getting data from inside 2 characters?

Tags: c#

I need the data within 2 Parentheses.

Something sorta like this.

```
textBox1.Text += "IndexError[0] : (untabbedIndex) in Program.cs";
```

I need to only get the untabbedIndex in the string.
I've tried splitting the string again, but no luck.

Comment: To clarify, you've got a string containing both an open parenthesis and a closed parenthesis and you want to get the entire string of characters between those two characters?  Is that correct?

Comment: Strings can be used as arrays with `mystring[index]`. That is not hard to find with Google. Please do some research before asking for free answers.

Comment: I've done hours of researching the answer, I'm new to c#, so i don't know how to correctly word it. I have been assigned to make a system terminal,

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets

Comment: Unfortunately it is hard to see what you did in those "hours researching"... I.e. searching for some sentences from the post like https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+data+within+2+Parentheses or actually reading on `Split` method should have lead to at least some information ( including `input.Split('(', ')')[1];`). For future question please actually show what you've tried (preferably as [MCVE]) and explain how it did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you might approach this.  The simplest to understand might be to use simple string methods to search for the position of the sentinel characters,'(' and ')' using string.IndexOf(), and then to use the string.Substring() method to find the result.  Understanding string manipulation in C# will serve you well.

```
// set input string
const string input = "IndexError[0] : (untabbedIndex) in Program.cs";

// find first of '(' in input string
int indexOpen = input.IndexOf('(');

if (indexOpen >= 0)  // did we find '(' ?
{
    // find first occurrence of ')' after '('
    int indexClose = input.IndexOf(')', indexOpen);

    if (indexClose >= 0) // did we find ')' ?
    {
        // get a substring of the input using the 2 calculated index values
        var innerText = input.Substring(indexOpen + 1, indexClose - indexOpen - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(innerText);
    }
    else
    {
        // no ')' found
        Console.WriteLine("Missing ')'");
    }
}
else
{
    // no '(' found
    Console.WriteLine("Missing '('");
}
```

Another way you might do this, but more advanced, is by using a regular expression. As mentioned before, a very good explanation of how to do that exists here:  [How do I extract text that lies between parentheses (round brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets).

Comment: I figured out the solution to my issue. All is taken care of. Thank you.